# Application defined or object defined error in creating macro for pivot

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop a macro for PivotTable. I am getting *Invalid procedure call or argument error*:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet1!R1C1:R33C10", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet3!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Comment: is that the complete error message?